# Angularjs не отображает русские символы

Tags: angularjs

Добрый день,
пишу

```
$scope.Students = [ {"id": "1","Fio": "Ivanov"},{"id": "2","Fio": "Петров"},{"id": "3","Fio": "Аргунов"},{"id": "55","Fio": "Ракзин Роман"}];
```

Потом отображаю

```
<li ng-repeat="Student in Students" >
    <a ng-href="#">{{Student.Fio}}</a>
</li>
```

Но вместо русских слов вижу ромбы с вопросом внутри. Что здесь может быть с кодировкой?

При этом- все другие русские символы отображаются нормально.

Поставил потом ещё `<html lang="ru" ng-app="app">` , но всё равно.

Спасибо.

Comment: возможно, файл, в котором инициализация `$scope.Students`, сохранен в cp12551, а html файл - в utf-8.

Comment: <meta charset="utf-8">
есть в head?

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 в мета - это хорошо, но нужно чтоб еще и файл был сохранен в ней, любой нормальный редактор это показывает, возьмите хоть [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html), в строке статуса можно посмотреть и переключить кодировку.